# Profile page swift 3 errors

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

This is the code that I have created for my profile page but it has some mistakes that i would like to adjust.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAuth
import Firebase


class ProfileClass: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var userImagePicker: RoundButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var ProfilePicture: RoundImage!
    @IBOutlet weak var usernameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageLoader: UIActivityIndicatorView!


    var loggedInUser = AnyObject?()
    var databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    var storageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference()
    var imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.loggedInUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser

        self.databaseRef.child("user_profile").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType(.Value) { (snapshot:FIRDataSnapshot) in


            if(snapshot.value!["usernameField"] !== nil) {

            self.usernameField.text = snapshot.value!["usernameField"] as? String

            }
            if(snapshot.value!["profile_pic"] !== nil) {

            let databaseProfilePic = snapshot.value!["profile_pic"]
            as! String
                let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string: databaseProfilePic)!)

                self.setProfilePicture(self.ProfilePicture,imageToSet:UIImage(data:data!)!)

            }
        }
    }


    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    @IBAction func logoutTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let firebaseAuth = FIRAuth.auth()
        do {
            try firebaseAuth?.signOut()
        } catch let signOutError as NSError {
            print ("Error signing out: %@", signOutError)
        }
     self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToLogin", sender: self)
    }


    @IBAction func TapProfileButton(_ sender: RoundButton) {

        let myActionShett = UIAlertController(title:"Profile Picture",message:"Select",preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.actionSheet)

        let viewPicture = UIAlertAction(title: "View Picture", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in

            let imageView = sender.view as! RoundImage
            let newImageView = RoundImage(image: imageView.image)

            newImageView.frame = self.view.frame

            newImageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
            newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            newImageView.userInteractionEnabled = true

            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target:self,action:#selector(self.dismissFullScreenImage))

            newImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            self.view.addSubview(newImageView)

        }

        let photoGallery = UIAlertAction(title: "Photos", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default) { (action) in

            if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum)
            {
            self.imagePicker.delegate = self
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.savedPhotosAlbum
            self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
            self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

        }

        let camera = UIAlertAction(title: "Camera", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default)
        {  (action) in

       if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera)

       {

        self.imagePicker.delegate = self
        self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
        self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true
        self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }

        }

    myActionShett.addAction(viewPicture)
    myActionShett.addAction(photoGallery)
    myActionShett.addAction(camera)
    myActionShett.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel, handler: nil))

    self.present(myActionShett, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }







    func dismissFullScreenImage(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
    sender.view?.removeFromSuperview()
    }



    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

        self.imageLoader.stopAnimating()
        setProfilePicture(self.ProfilePicture,imageToSet: image)

        if let imageData: NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.ProfilePicture, image!)!
        {
        let profilePicStorageRef = storageRef.child("user_profiles/\(self.loggedInUser!.uid)/profile_pic")

            let uploadTask = profilePicStorageRef.putData(imageData, metadata: nil)
            {metadata,error in

            if(error == nil)
            {
              let downloadUrl = metadata!.downloadUrl()
              self.databaseRef.child("user_profile").child(self.loggedInUser!.uid).child("profile_pic").setValue(downloadUrl!.absoluteString)
            }
            else
            {
             print(error?.localizedDescription)

           }
                self.imageLoader.stopAnimating()

            }
          }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
}
```

Comment: the errors list is in the image that i posted near "someone can help me?"

Comment: You can't create an instance of `AnyObject` and you certainly can't create an instance of `AnyObject?`

Comment: so? what i have to create? @Paulw11

Comment: You want `var loggedInUser: FIRUser?`

Comment: Hi, you have missed a } bracket. Put this bracket just before viewDidLoad ending bracket

Comment: "var loggedInUser = AnyObject?()" change this line to    " var loggedInUser : AnyObject?" , You can not create empty object instatnce for AnyObject class

Comment: Re-write the code. While doing so, do not ignore any compiler warning and let Xcode help you using autocompletion.

Answer (score 2):

You have to give proper type. You can not initialize object of type AnyObject. and Obviously with not using AnyObject?.